# C++ 11 lambda callback in VS 2013 won't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I can't understand why my following code can't compile in VS 2013. The compiler just complains as follows, and I don't know how to fix it:

> e:\work\justtest\console\console.cpp(37): error C2664: 'bool
>   dfsFolder(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,std::function &)' : cannot convert argument 3 from
>   'main::' to
>   'std::function &'

```
bool dfsFolder(__in const wchar_t* folderPath, __in const wchar_t* ext, const std::function<bool(const std::wstring& wsFilePath)>& pFunc)
{

}

int main()
{
        auto path = LR"(F:\TODOWNLOAD\)";
        auto lambda = [&](const std::wstring& wsFilePath) mutable -> bool
        {
            wcout << wsFilePath << endl;
            return true;
        };
        dfsFolder(path, L"*.jpg", lambda);
}
```

Comment: It compiles with GCC 4.8

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to match the code: the last argument is a `std::function<...> const&` not a `std::function<...>&` as stated in the error. Does your actual code declare the `std::function<...>&` parameter as `const`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl, thank you very much. in fact, you solved my issue. shame on myself. I lost the 'const' in my declaration. however, i can't accept your comment as the answer. could you upload an answer, then I would mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: This is why you *really* need to post a minimal example *that you have confirmed reproduces the problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't seem to match the code: the last argument is a `std::function<...> const&` not a `std::function<...>&` as stated in the error. Does your actual code declare the `std::function<...>&` parameter as `const`?

Comment: If add the missing 'const' keyword in my declaration, my code will compile. thank you very much.